# GWT Editors - handling different layouts for view / edit / create

Tags: gwt, editor, requestfactory

I'm starting to work with the GWT editors framework.
My app allows to view some entities, edit them, or create new ones.
However, in each state, the layout of the form is a bit different -

1. Labels in "view" mode should become textboxes in "edit" and "create"
2. Some fields are only visible in edit/create mode but not in view mode
3. Some fields are only editable when creating but cannot be changed later on in edit
4. The general layout might differ (order of fields, location in the form)
5. Many, many more...

I know that this is a very very general question - I'm looking for best practices that will be powerful yet flexible to deal with those issues. What I'm afraid of is having to write three different editors...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't like to hear this but I create different editors for each. But finally, that's hardly more to implement than a different UIBinder with corresponding Composite for each editor. The subeditors are the same so it does not comprise that much work at the end of the day;